# from loop to Nested loops?

Tags: java

I have this program that returns a factorial of N.  For example, when entering 4,,, it will give  1! , 2! , 3!

How could I convert this to use nested loops?

```
public class OneForLoop
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        int N = input.nextInt();                
        int factorial = 1;   

        for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
             factorial *= i;         
             System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial); 
        }         
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want nested loops? What purpose do you intend them to serve?

Comment: `for (int j = 1; j < 2; j ++) for (int i = 1; i < N; i ++) ...`? I don't think a nested loop is needed to compute the factorial sensibly.

Comment: its a requirement to do both one loop and a nested loop

Comment: But what do you want your code to do?

Comment: the same out put but with nested loops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If written as nested loops it would look like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
{
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
         factorial *= j;
    }
    System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial); 
}
```

Result:

```
Enter a number : 10
1! = 1
2! = 2
3! = 6
4! = 24
5! = 120
6! = 720
7! = 5040
8! = 40320
9! = 362880
```

This program gives the same result as yours, it just takes longer to do so. What you have already is fine. Note also that the factorial function grows very quickly so an `int` will be too small to hold the result for even moderately large N.

If you want to include `10!` in the result you need to change the condition for `i < N` to `i <= N`.

Comment: no it wont give the same result
try seting N as 10 and see the difference

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now. Just tested it and the updated version works exactly as yours does for N=10.

Comment: make sure of it, still its giving me different outputs

Comment: I double-checked it and it is still giving the right result. Perhaps if we wait another user will check the code and post here whether it is correct or incorrect. While you are waiting you could examine the code and see if you can find the error yourself.

Comment: My solution is basically the same, and the results are identical. Maybe @WM posted code that's different than what he's using to test on his machine.

Comment: @WM: "Make sure of it?" It's *your* homework, *you* should make sure of it. Mark Byers was kind enough to help.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are calculating your factorial incrementally. Just recalculate it from scratch every time. Be advised that what you have now is better than what I'm posting, but this does follow your requirements.

```
public class TwoForLoops
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);     
        System.out.print("Enter a number : ");
        int N = input.nextInt();                
        int factorial = 1;   

        for (int i = 1; i < N; ++i)
        {
            factorial = 1;
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
            {
                 factorial *= j;         
            }
            System.out.println(i + "! = " + factorial);         
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: try setting N to 10 her and try it there... they are different

Comment: Uhmm, really? Because I get the same results on my machine. Maybe you posted the wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than just computing everything in a linear fashion, you could consider an inner loop which would do something like what you have in the outer loop.  Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider recursion a nested loop?

```
public long factorial(int n)
{
    if (n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * factorial(n - 1);
}

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    //print factorials of numbers 1 to 10
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        System.out.println(factorial(i));
}
```

Comment: @WM: You never actually said it needed to be a for-loop. You just said "nested loops". Recursion is certainly nested. Does this not count because there is no *explicit* loop?

Comment: you are splitting hairs :). Recursion is not what one would normally call a loop in a programming language, and it's obviously not the same thing in a homework context.